# Find an entire function $f$ such that $f(n+in)=0$ $\forall n\in \Bbb Z$

Tags: complex-analysis, factoring, infinite-product

> Find an entire function $f$ such that $f(n+in)=0$ for every integer $n$ ($n$ can be positive, negative or zero). Give the most elementary example.

This is a problem from Conway at the end of the Weierstrass factorization theorem section. Can anyone help me construct this infinite product? I know that's where this is heading, but I cannot seem to see what I need to do for this, the book lacks an example like this.

Edit: To be clear here I'm looking for an infinite product likely derived using the Weierstrass factorization theorem. Out of context, the book's wording is weak but that is what they surely mean.

Comment: *Hint:* $\sin(n \pi) = 0$ for every integer $n$.

Comment: I believe that the most elementary example is $f = 0$.

Comment: @WhatsUp this is certainly true haha, but I'm looking for an infinite product here. I think Martin is on the right track, I'm trying to work it out right now.

Comment: What about $0\times0\times0\times\cdots$?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos While these examples work, I am looking to use the Weierstrass Factorization Theorem here. I guess the books wording is pretty ambiguous taken out of the section.

Comment: You can look up the infinite product for the sine, and then adopt it to your problem.